# Obtener Archivos de google Drive - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, drive

he configurado todo lo necesario para guardar arhivos en google Drive
pero tengo la duda de como puedo de nuevo regresarlos para mostrarlos en una vista de Laravel

Así estoy guardadno :

```
$request->file("file")->store("","google");
```

cuando guardo algo, me regresa el nombre de la foto. pero no puedo acceder a ella para ver la foto desde las vistas.

Comment: Si lo tienes configurado en el filesystem entonces deberia de funcionar **Storage::disk('google')->get('tuarchivo')

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega eso es lo que igual he intentado hacer pero no encuentra el archivo por su nombre